# how do i support Yoruba in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i already have an Microsoft access spreadsheet that contain the yoruba words in one column of the database. but when i export is in a txt file and try to import it into phpmyadmin database the yoruba words become garbled.

utf8mb4_unicode_ci is the only format that supports typing in "yoruba" language in phpmyadmin.

right now my data is in gabbled form made up of "???????"

I have tried every step on the internet i could find including but not limited to altering the column and setting character set. still the data dose not change from ??? to the correct one

example

Yoruba-->  ìbùgbé  but this is what is shown "?b?gb?"

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version are you using? Does the text file look correct in a utf-aware text editor? In the phpMyAdmin Import tab, what is the setting in the "Encoding" dropdown? What is your file type -- CSV? I've just done this and that string works fine with my column as `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` (and  `latin1_swedish_ci` and `utf8_bin`, incidentally). After making the proper CSV file, I go to the Import tab and accept the default values  on the import page (specifically Character set of the file utf-8).

Comment: I just tried what you said and it didn't work. i don't know if i can add pictures.  First i exported from Microsoft access to Microsoft excel file. Then i clicked save as and saved the excel file as .CSV then in the import tab of my php my admin inside the empty table i clicked import.  Now i dont get garbled data BUT PARTS OF THE TEXT TOTALLY DISAPPEARED. THE ONES THAT NORMALLY WILL GIVE WE QUESTION MARKS BEFORE ARE NOT EVEN SHOWING IN THEIR COLUMN! Do you think something is wrong with my phpmyadmin?

Comment: Did you try opening the CSV file in a text editor? What sort of characters do you see there?